# Override __eq__ with more logic

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following python classes

```
class Message:

    def __init__(self, start_date, attributes):
        self.start_date = start_date
        self.attributes = attributes

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Message):
            return False

        if not self.attributes == other.attrubutes:
            return False

        are_consecutive_dates = False
        self_start_date= datetime.strptime(self.start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        other_start_date= datetime.strptime(other.start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        
        if not abs(self_start_date.toordinal() - other_start_date.toordinal()) == 1:
            return False

        return True


class Attribute:

    def __init__(self, attribute_a, attribute_b):
        self.attribute_a = attribute_a
        self.attribute_b = attribute_b

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Attribute):
            return False

        if not self.attribute_a == other.attribute_a:
            return False

        if not self.attribute_b == other.attribute_b:
            return False

        return True
```

From a business perspective, two messages are equals if have the same attributes and have consecutive dates

I have two questions:

1. Is valid to have some business logic inside the `__eq__`(like the dates are consecutive)?
2. If the above is valid, I would like to create a set and pass the
   Messages instances and discard the ones that are equals by the definition I just wrote, so
   how I need to override the `__hash__`?

Comment: It's worth noting that your current `__eq__` implementations are also incorrect because they should return NotImplemented when given a type that they do not recognize. I strongly recommend using `dataclasses` to define this special method (and `__hash__`) automatically.

Comment: if for the equality I just want to consider in this case the attribute  "attributes" but not start_date, its not worth to override the __eq__  by myself? or I can do the same with dataclasses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Messages are *equal* if they contain *consecutive* dates? That doesn't seem right. Equality normally has [three properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation):

- <del>Reflexive</del>: `a == a`. This relation isn't reflexive as messages aren't equal to themselves.
- Symmetric: if `a == b` then `b == a`. Your relation is symmetric since you use `abs`.
- <del>Transitive</del>: if `a == b` and `b == c` then `a == c`. It's not transitive. Jan 1 and Jan 3 are not consecutive even though both are consecutive with Jan 2.

By violating these properties you can't use your objects in sets or as dictionary keys. You can't usefully implement `__hash__` to match this definition of `__eq__`: a message isn't equal to itself, but its hash will be equal to itself. This will confuse any data structure that uses either method.

Don't use `__eq__` for this. It's not the right relation. Make a new method `are_consecutive`.

Comment: That good to know, I was thinking equality as bussisness concept, but I did not think like the technical explanation and what you mention totally make sense to me, was very instructive

Comment: Technically it is possible to have hashes "consistent" with this equals method - e.g. if every object's hash is 23 then equals implies same hash. It's not incorrect for non-equal objects to have the same hash. Other than that, this is the correct answer.

Comment: Another question came up based on the answer..is correct to have ie the Message class has two attributes "start_date" and "attributes" is valid to just consider "attributes" to override the __eq__ base on the rules mentioned on the answer? or also violate the properties for equality?

Comment: @kaya3 Good point. I've hedged my answer with "usefully". :)

Comment: @jam That's more acceptable, yes. There's no technical issue with that `__eq__` definition. However, I still wouldn't do that. I don't like the idea of ignoring a property during an equality check. IMO it's best to only use `__eq__` for straight up *equality* and not try to extend it to some looser notion of *equivalence*. I'm thinking more about readability now, not confusing people reading the code. It's better to be explicit and use a named method: `has_same_attributes_as` or `same_contents` or `is_resend_of`.

Comment: Good point! totally agree with have more readable code thanks for the clarification